# Google analytics: Product Detail Views metrics do not count

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I trying to count detail views page on my site. But "Product Detail Views" metrics still not show in google analytics
http://skrinshoter.ru/s/290819/g1yfpQCE

I had pasted `DataLayer.push()` code, according to the manual, providing by link
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce
http://skrinshoter.ru/s/290819/yaoJNeOP

Debug info in a console:
http://skrinshoter.ru/s/290819/CicaxN0v

his my sample code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>

<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

dataLayer.push({
    'ecommerce': {
        'detail': {
            'products': [{
                'name': 'test product 6',         // Name or ID is required.
                'id': 'id-6',
                'price': '13',
                'category': 'category 1',
            },

            ]
        }
    }
});

</script>


<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','UA-1234');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

<body>
... 
</body>
</html>
```

Why Product Detail Views metrics not count (and do not show) in ga?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code (but please update the Google Tag Manager snippet with your own):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>

<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','UA-1234');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->


<script>
dataLayer.push({
    'ecommerce': {
        'detail': {
            'products': [{
                'name': 'test product 6',         // Name or ID is required.
                'id': 'id-6',
                'price': '13',
                'category': 'category 1',
            },

            ]
        }
    }
});

</script>

<body>
... 
</body>
</html>
```

What this does is:

1. Load the GTM-snippet
2. The GTM-snippet declares an empty object called **dataLayer**
3. After declaring the empty dataLayer, you can use the **dataLayer.push** function to push some new events (with additional data in it like the product name, etc.) to the dataLayer object

The dataLayer object should be created **before** you perform a dataLayer.push(). Creating an empty dataLayer object is something what the default GTM-snippet does for you.

So you should remove the dataLayer initialization on line 6, as this is already done in the GTM script. And you should load the GTM-snippet *before* the dataLayer.push event.

More helpful info about this in the official developer guide at: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I still have some problem with it.
I make change as you say. Here my code:
http://skrinshoter.ru/s/080919/KRNLM5NS

But detal view metrics still not counts in ga
http://skrinshoter.ru/s/080919/mxjGFWuf

Can you give me some help?

Comment: Install the chrome extension Google Analytics Debugger. It will print in the javascript console all actions related to analytics. You can verify if it is executing the detail snippet or not. There is another extension from Google that is useful but I think this one is sufficient.

Comment: @SafronovSergey can you please share your Google Tag Manager setup with some screenshots? You should add the default Google Analytics tag for Page Views in GTM and you should do some additional configuration in GTM in order to send the enhanced ecommerce data (that you push to the dataLayer with the code snippet above) to Google Analytics.